# How to set up mongodb with express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

New to Express App , I am trying to setup mongodb using express and node.js. I have some issues if i can get some help in this area. i tried to add directories refrences so you can have idea.

1- var `config` is coming undefined not sure path is correct.

2- getting SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word for 
`require('./config/express')(app);`.

Basically trying to have app running with local mongodb.

server > app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri, config.mongo.options);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
    process.exit(-1);
});


// Setup server
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);


require('./config/express')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

// Start server
function startServer() {
    server.listen(config.port, config.ip, function() {
        console.log('Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', config.port, app.get('env'));
    });
}

setImmediate(startServer);

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

server > config > express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('./config/environment');
var session = require('express-session');
var connectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoStore = connectMongo(session);

export default function(app) {
    var env = app.get('env');

    app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    /*app.use(compression());*/
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));

    app.set('appPath', path.join(config.root, 'client'));

    if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
        app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
        app.use(express.static(app.get('appPath')));
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

server > config > environment > development.js

```
module.exports = {

  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost/test-modeler-dev'
  },

  // Seed database on startup
  seedDB: false

};
```

Comment: It's difficult to identitify the issue without knowing what the directory structure for `./config` is. From the looks of it, there isn't an `index.js` file in `./config/environment` directory, hence it is undefined. Have to tried using a specific file like `require('./config/environment/development.js')` instead?

Comment: config is under server and server is on root level as i mentioned in development.js

Comment: What other files are there in the `./config/environment` directory? If there is only `development.js` then you need to use `require('./config/environment/development.js')` instead, since the module loader will not resolve that name by default.

Comment: how about second issue ?

Comment: Again, it's very hard to tell what's wrong without looking at the code inside `./config/express` but my guess is that you're running this on a version of Node.js which doesn't support a feature being used in the file. If you're using ES6 features then make sure you are on Node 6.x.x+ at least.

Comment: config/express.js is part of question

Comment: Either you've labelled a file wrong above, or pasted the wrong file :)

Comment: For #2, do you mind pasting in the whole line of the error?

Comment: Based on how you use config, shouldn't config be require('./config/environment/development'); ?

Comment: This seems to be a problem at line no. 3 in **express.js** file above (I'm assuming this was supposed to be server > config > express.js and was mislabeled): `import compression from 'compression';*/` Notice the `*/` at the end.

Comment: yes i corrected please see the file structure for express.js

Comment: `\test\server\config\express.js:23
export default function(app) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sh529u\test\server\app.js:30:1)
`

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running?

Comment: @UzairSajid was thinking the same thing. Maybe ```module.exports = function (app)``` will fix it

Comment: using node version 4.4.5

Comment: @Brian Yes that seems to be it. ES6 syntax isn't fully supported in older versions of Node like 4.4.5.

Comment: @hussain if you need to use the newer syntax, you should update Node to the latest LTS release like 6.9.0+.

Comment: i dont need compression module i removed it from the file , what are other problems related to syntax, Can you help to solve the problem with node version 4.4.5 ?

Answer (score -1):

As it was pointed out in the comments of the question, your problem is that you are using newer JavaScript features with an older version of Node. To get around the current error, you should change this line in *server > config > express.js*:

```
// ...
export default function(app) {
// ...
```

To

```
// ...
module.exports = function(app) {
// ...
```

This should solve this particular problem. But if the code you are using is using other features of ECMAScript 2015 that aren't supported by your version of Node, then you have two options:

- Update to the [latest version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) of Node.js here.
- Refactor all of your code remove all ECMAScript 2015 features to ensure that it works with your version of Node.js.

Hope this helps.